# Programatically checking input via jQuery not calling form's .change() event?

Tags: jquery, forms, checkbox

So I'm using jQuery to skin some form checkboxes, and am doing something like the following:

```
$('.sexyCheckBox').on("click", function(e) {
    var clickedInput = $(this).parent().find("input");
    clickedInput.prop("checked", !clickedInput.prop("checked"));
}
```

However, it seems that, even though the checkbox in form is indeed being toggled, the form's `.change()` event is not being called.

Is this a bug in jQuery or am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Programatic changes to inputs value does not fire the change event, you need to trigger it manually. The change event will be triggered only if the user changes the value of an input element.

```
clickedInput.prop("checked", !clickedInput.prop("checked")).change();
```

another way to write this is

```
clickedInput.prop("checked", function (i, val) {
    return !val;
}).change();//or .trigger('change')
```